# Calculate the frequency of each number as each number is generated using the arrays and print the number

Tags: c

Write a C program using the arrays to eliminate the duplicate numbers. Generate 50 random
numbers between 50 and 150 using rand function. Insert the random numbers to the array with
a size 50. As each number is generated, print it only if it’s not a duplicate of a number already
generated. Provide for the “worst-case” in which all 50 numbers are different.

Comment: Ok, What have you tried so far?

Comment: I didn't get thid question completely Im new to coding. Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

This how I would approach it:

The easier way for me is to have a *frequency table* (an array of size 151), since you are dealing with a short range of numbers.

1. Initialize the *array* with 0's (Could use `memset()` here).
2. Get a random number within your range (lets say **n**)
3. Check that `array[n]` is 0.
4. If it is, print the number and increment the array by one (`array[n]++`)
5. If not, print an error
6. Repeat until you've read 50 numbers

Comment: 101 numbers will be enough

Comment: `size_r arr[101] = {0,};` will be enough.